# build documentation automatically for macros

Tags: sas, documentation

I want to build a documentation `pdf` (or `html`) for a collection of `SAS` macros. Is there a canonic (or recommended) workflow that I can follow ?

I'm thinking of exporting all my macros and extract title, description, examples, variable descriptions and code using `R` and `Regex` then use `markdown` to build a nicely laid out `pdf` that I can update in a few steps whenever I add a macro or change descriptions or examples (I want to avoid copy/paste at all cost).

It'd be quite tedious and unflexible though and I might be reinventing the wheel.

My macros all look like this:

```
*--------------------------------------------------------;
* ASSERT_EXIST                                           ;
* Fails explicitely when a table doesn't exist           ;
* Accepts a list of tables as input                      ;
*--------------------------------------------------------;
/* EXAMPLES
%assert_exist(not_a_table);   * prints explicit error and aborts;
%assert_exist(sashelp.class); * does nothing;
%assert_exist(sashelp.cars not_a_table sashelp.class); * prints explicit error and aborts;
*/
%macro assert_exist
(data /* table or list of tables */
);
%local i table;
%do i=1 %to %sysfunc(countw(&data,%str( )));
  %let table = %scan(&data,&i,%str( ));
  %if not %sysfunc(exist(&table)) %then %do;
    %put ERROR: Table &table doesnt exist!;
    %abort;
  %end;
%end;
%mend;

*----------------------------------------------;
* DROP                                         ;
* Delete table or list of tables               ;
* Default deletes all tables starting with _   ;
*----------------------------------------------;
/* EXAMPLES
data _x;
input char1 $ num1;
datalines;
a 1
b 2
;
%put %sysfunc(exist(_x)); * 1;
%drop(_x);
%put %sysfunc(exist(_x)); * 0;
*/
%macro drop
(data /* Name of table to drop, end name of table with ':' to delete all tables with this prefix */
);
%if &data= %then %let data = _:;
proc datasets nolist;
    delete &data;
run;
%mend;

*--------------------------------------------------------;
* HEAD                                                   ;
* select top rows                                        ;
*--------------------------------------------------------;
/* EXAMPLES
%head(sashelp.class,2) * keep only 2 first rows;
* %drop(_TEMP_); * clean up;
*/
%macro head
(data  /* source table */
,n     /* number of rows to keep */
,out   /* output table */
);
/* default values, checks, initialisations */
%if &data= %then %let data = _TEMP_;
%if &out=  %then %let out  = _TEMP_;
%if &out=. %then %let out  = &data;
%assert_exist(&data)
proc sql inobs=&n;
  CREATE TABLE &out AS
  SELECT *
  FROM &data;
quit;
%mend;
```

My collection of macros is growing I'd like to respect good practice as much as possible but I've not been able to find much information relative to good documentation in `SAS`.

@Allan-Bowe gave a great answer which is probably the best practice, but unfortunately I have no way to install `doxygen` from my work computer, so I'm looking for other solutions not requiring external software.

Comment: I wrote a paper on using SAS to parse standard macro headers, from an autocall library, then use ODS HTML to generate documentation. Nothing shocking: https://www.lexjansen.com/nesug/nesug04/po/po04.pdf

Comment: You don't need admin rights to install doxygen - just download the .exe and update your PATH (environment variables for your account) to include the directory where you saved it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to re-invent the wheel - a great approach for documentation is [doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/).

We use it for the open source SASjs [Macro Core library](http://github.com/sasjs/core) (which also lists a lot of good practices for SAS Macro development).

Simply define your attributes in the header (markdown is accepted), eg:

```
/**
  @file
  @brief Logs a key value pair a control dataset
  @details If the dataset does not exist, it is created.  Usage:

      %mp_setkeyvalue(someindex,22,type=N)
      %mp_setkeyvalue(somenewindex,somevalue)

  @param key Provide a key on which to perform the lookup
  @param value Provide a value
  @param type= either C or N will populate valc and valn respectively.  C is
               default.
  @param libds= define the target table to hold the parameters
  @version 9.2
  @author Allan Bowe
  @source https://github.com/sasjs/core

**/
```

Then simply point doxygen at your source folder, tell it which config file to use (a good one for SAS is [here](https://github.com/sasjs/core/blob/main/doxy/Doxyfile)) and then choose an output directory for your documentation.

It'll look like [this](https://core.sasjs.io).

There's no pdf option, but it can create files in DOCBOOK format that can be used to generate a pdf:  http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/config.html#config_docbook

UPDATE - we recently added doxygen support to [SASjs](http://cli.sasjs.io/doc) - with a single command (`sasjs doc`) you can document all your jobs, and even generate a graphviz data lineage diagram, integrated into the output.

Overview:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ESNdCtXKRrw

Comment: Yes, I usually put mine in the `details` attribute, as I can then use markdown for code formatting!  http://www.stack.nl/~dimitri/doxygen/manual/commands.html#cmddetails

Comment: In the answer it is stated : "There's no pdf option", there is indeed no direct PDF option, but the option to generate LaTeX output is present as well as a Makefile (and make.bat) to convert the LaTeX directly to a PDF.

Answer (score 1):

You already seem to be placing the parameter definitions on separate lines. That should help with parsing the source files. Also add the macro name to the %MEND statement so that your parsing code can have a double check that it didn't find the wrong one.

I would also recommend moving your comment blocks into the macro.

```
%macro assert_exist
(data /* table or list of tables */
);
/*--------------------------------------------------------;
* ASSERT_EXIST                                           ;
* Fails explicitely when a table doesn't exist           ;
* Accepts a list of tables as input                      ;
*--------------------------------------------------------;
EXAMPLES
%assert_exist(not_a_table);   * prints explicit error and aborts;
%assert_exist(sashelp.class); * does nothing;
%assert_exist(sashelp.cars not_a_table sashelp.class); * prints explicit error and aborts;
*/
%local i table;
%do i=1 %to %sysfunc(countw(&data,%str( )));
  %let table = %scan(&data,&i,%str( ));
  %if not %sysfunc(exist(&table)) %then %do;
    %put ERROR: Table &table doesnt exist!;
    %abort;
  %end;
%end;
%mend assert_exist;
```

Comment: About moving the macro block I'm guessing it's to be able to see the description when displaying the macro code, but how do can one display this code ? Would you advise against putting this comment block just after the first line (`%macro assert_exist`)? It makes more sense to me to see the description block before the parameters.

Comment: Typically I add a /* */ comment with a short (usually one line) description between the macro name and the parameter list.  Then the header block after the the macro statement provides the detailed description, notes, usage examples. https://github.com/sasutils/macros/blob/master/csvfile.sas  Not including things before/after the macro will make it easier to parse. Also easier to store in autocall library.  The first time you call a macro using autocall it %includes to whole file. So any extra stuff before or after gets  interpreted as SAs statements to run now.

Comment: That made perfect sense with your example, thanks a lot